# How to sort with Jquery when some numbers end in k?

Tags: jquery

All of the posts I've found seem to be dealing with converting 1000 into 1k. What I'd like to do is the opposite. I have a sorting function that I use to sort some table data that is both alpha and numeric. It works but, one page where it is used has many numbers that crest 1000 and have been changed to 1k, 2k, etc. I would like to be able to sort them along with the less than 1k numbers like 999, 998, etc. My thought was that if I could just convert them to their full value on page load then my sorting function would still work. This is all being done using a Chrome Extension I've written that adds functionality to an existing game. The sorting function is below. Does it make more sense to re-write this function to deal with the potential k numbers or write a different function to convert them? Any help is appreciated.

```
function comparer(index) {
    return function(a, b) {
        var valA = getCellValue(a, index), valA2 = numFormatter('valA'), valB = getCellValue(b, index), valB2 = numFormatter('valB')
        return $.isNumeric(valA2) && $.isNumeric(valB2) ? valA2 - valB2 : valA2.toString().localeCompare(valB2)
    }
    }

function getCellValue(row, index){ return $(row).children('td').eq(index).text() }

function numFormatter(num) {
    if(num > 999 && num < 1000000){
        return (num*1000).toFixed(0) - 'k';
    }
    }
```

Comment: why don't you convert them in the sort logic? Or use the data attribute

Comment: I fumbled a bit with trying to do exactly that but, wasn't able to actually get anything working. Just a lot of errors in the console...

Answer (score 1):

Simple conversion method that matches the k and multiplies the number

```js
const multi = { k: 1000, m: 1000000};
const convertNum = str => {
  const parts = str.match(/([\d.]+)([km])?/);
  return +parts[1] * (parts[2] ? multi[parts[2]] : 1);
}

const data = ['1', '1k', '1m', '1001', '1.1k', '2.2k', '2.1k', '999', '0.9m']

data.sort((a,b) => convertNum(a) - convertNum(b))

console.log(data);
```

Comment: I apologize for not including the line that grabs the values from the td elements. I've edited the original post.

Comment: I'm unsure how to plug in your code to my function. Is this a direct replacement for my function?

Comment: modified original post with a non-working try at converting the k numbers back to 1000s

Comment: unsure what your issue is. You just need to replace your sort line with the sort line above. Just change the convertNum to grab the text from the cell.

Comment: It still "sorts" the values but it doesn't do anything with the Ks and the sorting doesn't seem to make sense to me.